# Game Center issue in iOS 6

Tags: ios5, ios6, game-center, leaderboard

I am implementing Game Center in my app and I am having an issue trying to read the leaderboardCategory property in iOS 6.

Here's how I'm presenting the GKGameCenterViewController:

```
    GKGameCenterViewController *gcViewController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc]init];
    [gcViewController setLeaderboardCategory:currentLeaderboard];
    [gcViewController setGameCenterDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:gcViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [gcViewController release];
```

Then when the delegate is called, I check to see what the leaderboardCategory property shows:

```
-(void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController{
    NSLog(@"%@", gameCenterViewController.leaderboardCategory);
}
```

The trouble is that no matter which leader boards I switch to before dismissing, it always shows the first one I passed in.

According to Apple's docs:

> When the leaderboard is presented, the value of this property
>   determines which leaderboard content is displayed to the player. As
>   the player changes which leaderboard content they view, the
>   leaderboardCategory property is automatically updated. For example, to
>   preserve the player’s selections, you can read the leaderboardCategory
>   property after the screen is dismissed, and set that value the next
>   time you initialize the view controller.

Now, I tried using GKLeaderboardViewController as well, but with no success. However, when I use GKLeaderboardViewController in iOS 5 (GKGameCenterViewController isn't available before iOS 6), the "category" property **is** updated as Apple's docs suggest.

What am I missing?